# Nested indexing in NumPy einsum?

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting, numpy-einsum

I'm trying to write the following expression using the einsum function in NumPy:

```
for j in range(100):
    p[j] = 0
    for i in range(100):
        if i!=j:
            p[j] += S[i,j]*B[T[i,j], i]
```

`p.shape = (1,100)`
`S.shape = (100,100)`
`B.shape = (N,100)`
`T.shape = (100,100)`

N is chosen such that it exceeds the maximum value in the matrix T.

Is this possible to implement using the einsum function?
If not, is there another way to optimise this?

I've searched the documentation, and it looks like it'll need some kind of broadcasting operation before being inserted into the einsum expression. But I can't get the expression right.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `einsum` has any nested indexing. But you can use vectorization:

```
import numpy as np

# Preliminaries:
S = np.random.rand(100, 100)
B = np.random.rand(10, 100)
T = np.random.randint(10, size=(100, 100))

# Solution:
idx = np.arange(100)[:, None]
arr = S * B[T, idx]

p = arr.sum(axis=0) - arr.diagonal()
```

I subtract the diagonal to account for the fact that you don't want to sum when `i == j`. You may choose to use `keepdims=True` in the sum to get `p` as shape `(1, 100)` instead.

Comment: `np.einsum('ij,ij->j', S, B[T, idx])` performs the sum/multiply, but probably without much of an improvement in speed.